# How to replace a line with a new line using Java

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filewriter

Using a Buffer reader I parse throughout a file. If Oranges: pattern is found, I want to replace it with ApplesAndOranges.

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(resourcesFilePath))) {

            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
if (line.startsWith("Oranges:")){
                        int startIndex = line.indexOf(":");
                        line = line.substring(startIndex + 2);
                        String updatedLine = "ApplesAndOranges";
                        updateLine(line,  updatedLine);
```

I call a method updateLine and I pass my original line as well as the updated line value.

```
private static void updateLine(String toUpdate, String updated) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(resourcesFilePath));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(resourcesFilePath+".out"), "UTF-8");
    String line;

    while ((line = file.readLine()) != null)
    {
        line = line.replace(toUpdate, updated);
        writer.println(line);
    }
    file.close();
    if (writer.checkError())
        throw new IOException("Can't Write To File"+ resourcesFilePath);
    writer.close();
}
```

To get the file to update I have to save it with a different name (resourcesFilePath+".out"). If I use the original file name the saved version become blank.
So here is my question, how can I replace a line with any value in the original file without losing any data.

Comment: Read each line, process it, write it to a new file. When you're done, delete the old file and rename the new file into it's place

Comment: You need to re-write the file with the new line. You can't use the line.replace

Comment: Thanks MadProgrammer for your input. I have used an Array<List> to re-write the data. I am not sure if this is an over kill or not as I only need to replace one line in that resources file. Please post your comment as answer to accept it accordingly. And can you confirm that there is no way around replacing that line without re-wrting the entire file?

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use the regular expressions (RegExp) like this:

str = str.replaceAll("^Orange:(.*)", "OrangeAndApples:$1");

It's an example and maybe it's not excactly what you want, but here, in the first parameter, the expression in parentesis is called a capturing group. The expression found will be replaced by the second parameter and the $1 will be replaced by the value of the capturing group. In our example Orange:Hello at the beggining of a line will be replaced by OrangeAndApples:Hello.

In your code, it seams you create one file per line ... maybe inlining the sub-method would be better.

```
try (
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(resourcesFilePath));
    BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(outputFilePath, charset);
) {
    String line;

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String repl = line.replaceAll("Orange:(.*)","OrangeAndApples:$1");
        writer.writeln(repl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! But my goal is overwrite the original file with the new data. in your example, you write the data to outputfilePath. and I want to write it to resourcesFilePath. This seems to do the trick, but if I attempted to overwrite the original file, the file becomes blank.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to write over everything in your original final would be to read in everything - changing whatever you want to change and closing the stream. Afterwards open up the file again, then overwrite the file and all its lines with the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RandomAccessFile to write to the file, and nio.Files to read the bytes from it. In this case, I put it as a string.

You can also read the file with RandomAccessFile, but it is easier to do it this way, in my opinion.

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.*;

public void replace(File file){
    try {
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
    Path p = Paths.get(file.toURI());
    String line = new String(Files.readAllBytes(p));
    if(line.startsWith("Oranges:")){
    line.replaceAll("Oranges:", "ApplesandOranges:");
        raf.writeUTF(line);
    }
    raf.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```